# How to set Spanish as display language when Spanish (Mexico) is selected on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, localization, windows-phone

When I change the phone language settings on Windows Phone to a culture that is not supported by my app, it will fall back to the neutral language in the app. It does this even if there is a related culture so if I e.g choose es-US, it falls back to the neutral (en-GB in my case). Android and iOS phones, however, will choose es-ES instead and this behavior I want to mimic in my Windows Phone app.
The solution I use is to hard code supported cultures, get the selected culture, and then set the UI culture to es-ES in the case es-US is chosen.
Is there a better, less cumbersome, way?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you support specifically es-ES culture, so when switch to es-US, there isn't a culture compatible and the app switch to the neutral one, en-GB. If you want to use "es" culture whenever the user have a "es-*" culture, you need to support the "es" culture, without country code in it. this way, every time a user had a "es-*" culture, your app use the "es" country independent culture. for this you need:

1. Support Spanish culture in your project (without country specific variant)
2. name your resource file this way: resourcefilename.es.resx

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Changed the name of the Spanish resource file according to the above but it didn't work; when starting the app with Spanish set as display language (no matter country) it displays English. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Do you have a MSDN reference for your suggested solution?

Comment: Please see this msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Hmm...can't seem to find anything there that supports your suggested solution, thanks anyway.